# Multiple jobs or multiple pipelines in one job in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use case where I want to run 2 independent processing flows on Flink.
So 2 flows would look like

Source1 -> operator1 -> Sink1

Source2 -> operator2 -> Sink2

I want to re-use the same Flink cluster for both flows. I can think of doing this in 2 ways:

1) submit 2 different jobs on the same Flink application

2) Setup 2 pipelines in same job

I was able to setup the first option, but not sure how to do the second option.
Has anyone tried such a setup before? 
What is the advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply create multiple pipelines (with separate or shared source consumers) in your setupJob() method. Here is an example:

```
private void buildPipeline(StreamExecutionEnvironment env, String sourceName, String sinkName) {
    DataStream<T> stream = env
            .addSource(getInputs().get(sourceName))
            .name(sourceName);
    stream = stream.filter(evt -> filter());
    ....
}

@Override
public void setupJob(AthenaFlinkJobConfiguration jobConfig, StreamExecutionEnvironment env) throws Exception {
    ...
    buildPipeline(env, sourceTopic1, sink1, ...);
    buildPipeline(env, sourceTopic2, sink2, ...);
    ...
}
```

Here is a quick contrast of both approaches. The Pros/Cons of using separate jobs:

- [+] Code is simpler.
- [+] Greater flexibility to set low-level configuration (fault tolerance mechanism, heap size, parallelism, etc.)
- [-] Higher infrastructure costs since resources are not shared.
- [-] Maintenance & monitoring are more complex and time consuming.

The benefits of using separate pipeline in a single job:

- [+] Monitoring and debugging a single job is easier.
- [+] Hotfixes are committed into a single repo and deployed to a single environment.
- [+] Economical: decreases infrastructure hardware and operational costs.
- [-] Can't bound single pipeline usage.
- [-] Failures in one pipeline with affect the other pipeline.
- [-] Back-pressure in one pipeline could affect the whole job since a single checkpoint is snapshotted per job.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach can be implemented by defining two independent pipelines in the same `StreamExecutionEnvironment` and just calling `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute()` once.

I would use the first approach because it gives you better isolation. Flink restarts the whole job in case of a failure. Hence, both pipelines will be reset and restart in case of a failure, if you implement both pipelines in the same job. Also you can independently take savepoints if you follow approach one.