# What's the difference between flink application cluster and job cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am reading at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/concepts/glossary.html#flink-application-cluster and https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/concepts/glossary.html#flink-job-cluster

Flink Application Cluster

> A Flink Application Cluster is a dedicated Flink Cluster that only executes Flink Jobs from one Flink Application. The lifetime of the Flink Cluster is bound to the lifetime of the Flink Application.

Flink Job Cluster:

> A Flink Job Cluster is a dedicated Flink Cluster that only executes a single Flink Job. The lifetime of the Flink Cluster is bound to the lifetime of the Flink Job.

I often submit flink code jar to YARN, each flink code jar will kick off a long running YARN application with different YARN application id.

I got two questions here:

1. I don't know in which mode my application is running,  `flink application cluster` or `flink job cluster`?
2. What's the good to differentiate these two cluster mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [Per-Job mode has been deprecated in 1.15](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/overview/#per-job-mode-deprecated).

[Flink application](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/concepts/glossary/#flink-application): A Flink application is a Java Application that submits one or multiple Flink Jobs from the main() method (or by some other means). Submitting jobs is usually done by calling execute() on an execution environment.

A Flink application can contain multiple jobs, if there are two distinct Jobs in the same main class. One example is when you want to read from two different sources with different environment configuration.

A very basic example of one Flink application running two Jobs:

```
public class FlinkApp{ //application
  public static void main(String arg[]){
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env1 = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env1.setParallelism(3);
    //add source and destination to env1
    env1.execute(); //Job 1

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env2 = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env2.setParallelism(6);
    //add source and destination to env2
    env2.execute(); //Job 2
  }
}
```

Also see this discussion - [Multiple jobs or multiple pipelines in one job in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009948/multiple-jobs-or-multiple-pipelines-in-one-job-in-flink)

> I don't know in which mode my application is running, flink
> application cluster or flink job cluster?

It depends on the target environment option you choose when you run the application. If the above application (Jar file) is run on a YARN cluster with deployment target as `--target yarn-per-job` the main method of the application will be run at the client that started the application, the jobs and their dependencies are sent to YARN JobManager and each Job will run on its own dedicated cluster in YARN.

The option `--target yarn-session` runs the client locally, sends the jobs and their dependencies to YARN JobManager and the two Jobs on the same cluster.

The option `--target yarn-application` runs main method and Jobs in YARN cluster. This option needs the Job's dependencies available on all nodes of the cluster.

> What's the good to differentiate these two cluster mode?

Application mode does not allow separation between the Jobs since they all run on the same cluster. A slow running Job may affect the other Job. It allows for faster deployment and recovery since the dependencies are already available at the nodes and there is no need to ship it every time the Job is restarted.

Per-Job mode runs the Jobs on their dedicated YARN clusters. Even if one Job slows or fails it will not affect the other Job.

Which mode you choose will affect the way you deploy, design the Flink application/jobs and the YARN cluster setup. Flink in version 1.16 recommends using application mode for production systems.